# Multiple NavigationBars showing when linking SwithUI Views

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, navigationbar, navigationview

I've got two SwiftUI Views that are separate files that I'm linking with a NavigationLink:

View1:

```
struct ViewOne: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
        VStack {
        NavigationLink(destination: ViewTwo()
       .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
) {
                Text("Go to second view")
            }
.navigationBarTitle(Text("First View"), displayMode: .inline)
            }}}}
```

View2:

```
struct ViewTwo: View {

        var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
            VStack {
                    Text("Hello world")
                }
    .navigationBarTitle(Text("Second View"), displayMode: .inline)
                }}}
```

Problem: On View2 I don't want the .navigationBarBackButton so I've set this to hidden within ViewOne but because I've set this to hidden it messes with the existing NavigationBar on ViewTwo and displays multiple NavigationBars

[image: View2]

How do I disable the navigationBarBackButton without it messing with the existing NavigationBar on View2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NavigationView` in one view hierarchy *should* be only one, so just remove it in `ViewTwo`:

```
struct ViewTwo: View {

        var body: some View {
            VStack {
               Text("Hello world")
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Second View"), displayMode: .inline)
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works but I guess SwiftUI isn't that advanced yet to show the changes to the NavigationBar on ViewTwo in the Canvas Editor on Xcode.